# Warning (fixltx2e)

Tags: warnings

I use

```
\documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mnras}
\usepackage{graphicx,natbib,times,amssymb}
```

and the warning

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty:
Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.
```

How do I remove the fixltx2e; I do not see it anywhere.
Thanks
R. Baer

Comment: Unfortunately the package is hard coded in the class `mnras`. But other than issuing the warning nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's only a warning, so you may safely ignore it.

Comment: If the warning really bothers you, you may add the line `\expandafter\def\csname ver@fixltx2e.sty\endcsname{}` before `\documentclass`. Personally, I'd live with the warning.

Comment: @samcarter: But the authors of `mnras` could do a check in the `.cls` file  for the year and include `fixltx2e` if the year is < 2015 ;-)

Comment: Adding an empty `fixltx2e.sty` next to your document also removes this warning.